# Onsubmit form is not working

Tags: ajax, onsubmit

Here is my form HTML & JavaScript Code that I want to click on the submit then run function `ExportPublication()`:

```
<form  onsubmit="ExportPublication()" class="form-horizontal" id="frmExportPublication" name="frmExportPublication" >
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">email Pa</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea name="emailBody" class="input-xlarge">file</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ExportPublicationButton" projectid="" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
function ExportPublication() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOutput", "Publication", new { area = "Cartable" })',
        data: $("#frmExportPublication").serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {
            ajaxWaiting.showWaiting();
        },
        success: function () {
            $("#message").show();
            ajaxWaiting.hideWaiting();
            $('#ExportPublication').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            ajaxWaiting.hideWaiting();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

When I click on submit, function is not working. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be like this:

```
   function ExportPublication() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOutput", "Publication", new { area = "Cartable" })',
        data: $("#frmExportPublication").serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {
            ajaxWaiting.showWaiting();
        },
        success: function () {
            $("#message").show();
            ajaxWaiting.hideWaiting();
            $('#ExportPublication').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            ajaxWaiting.hideWaiting();
        }
    });
    return false;
 }
```

Also in form onsubmit function should return a value.. ie;

```
  <form  onsubmit="return ExportPublication()" class="form-horizontal" id="frmExportPublication" name="frmExportPublication" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  <form  onsubmit="ExportPublication()" class="form-horizontal" id="frmExportPublication" name="frmExportPublication" >
```

if you can try binding the listener via javascript like below, works like a charm !

```
document.forms.frmExportPublication.onsubmit = ExportPublication;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luciferous/uUPWe/109/)  , have removed ur ajax calls from fiddle for brevity.